# R: rvest - share counter, xpath

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrap data using Rvest. I cannot scrape the number/text from the share counter at this [link](https://www.siepomaga.pl/kacper-szlyk): "753 udostępnienia".

I used Google Chrome plugin [XPath helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) to find Xpath. I prepared a simple R code:

```
library(rvest)
url2<- "https://www.siepomaga.pl/kacper-szlyk"
share_url<-html(url2)
share_url
share <- share_url %>%
 html_node(xpath ="/html[@class='turbolinks-progress-bar']/body/div[@id='page']/div[@class='causes-show']/div[@class='ui container']/div[@id='column-container']/div[@id='right-column']/div[@class='ui sticky']/div[@class='box with-padding']/div[@class='bordered-box share-box']/div[@class='content']/div[@class='ui grid two columns']/div[@class='share-counter']") %>% 
  html_text()
share
```

However result is equal NA. 
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution using `rvest`, without using the `xpath =` method. This also uses the pipe operator from the `dplyr` package, to simplify things:

```
library(tidyverse) # Contains the dplyr package
library(rvest)

siep_url <- "https://www.siepomaga.pl/kacper-szlyk"

counter <- siep_url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node(".share-counter") %>%  # The node comes from https://selectorgadget.com/, a useful selector tool
  html_text()
```

The output for this comes up like so:

```
[1] "\n\n755\nudostępnień\n"
```

You can clean that up using `gsub()`:

```
counter <- gsub("\n\n755\nudostępnień\n", "755 udostępnień", counter)
```

This returns `755 udostępnień`, as a character.  Hope this helps.

---

Disclaimer: Rather large language barrier, but translate.google.com did wonders.

Comment: Thanks, so in summary: 1) use SelectorGardget to get CSS, then manipulate with gsub to clean text.

Comment: Essentially, yes - you can check this answer as correct, if you'd like!